# <identifier> expected java error

Tags: java, html, sql, bluej

I keep getting a "identifier expected error" while making a human being shape on blueJ. So far, here is the code for the main class:

```
import java.awrt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Main here
 * 
 * @author Ibrahim Hmood
 * @version 03.27.2014
 */
public class main 
{
        public static void main (String[] args);
        Frame frame = newCricleDraw();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we)
            {
                system.exit(0);
            }
          }
        };//end of listener
        frame.setSize(600,600)
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

and here is the code for CircleDraw class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class CircleDraw extends Frame
{
    Shape squarehead = new;
    Ellipse2D.Float(200.0F, 40.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);

    Shape squareLeftArm = new;
    Rectangle2D.Double(165, 230,30, 50);

    Shape circleCenter = new;
    Circle2D.Double(165, 230, 30, 50);

    Shape squareNeck = new
    Square2D.Double(165, 230, 30,50);
    {
        //draw head
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(squareHead);
        ga.setPaint(color.Blue);
        ga.fill(squareHead);

        //draw arms
        ga.setPaint(Color.black);
        ga.draw(squareLeftArm);
        ga.fill(squareLeftArm);

        //draw center
        ga.setPaint(color.NavyBlue);
        ga.Draw(circleCenter);
        ga.fill(circleCenter);

        //draw neck

    }
}
```

This error continues to occur everytime I compile it for tests. So far I have not finished it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's not helpful. This is obviously a new Java programmer.

Comment: @mttdbrd Don't give me that. I've pin pointed one of the errors. There are tons of other typographical errors. The OP needs to learn how to type before they learn how to program. This question will not help anyone else.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis People come here for help with their programming. Your comment is not constructive or helpful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And there aren't "tons" of typographical errors. There are a few that are of exactly the same type. It only takes a few seconds to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @mttdbrd Off-topic questions: Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't care enough to argue about this. You should take it to meta, though. I'm sure it's been debated enough. See ajb's answer below for what I take to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Methods, including `main`, have to have their encode enclosed in curly braces.  So:

```
    public static void main (String[] args);
```

should be

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
```

Also, curly braces `{ }` and parentheses `( )` have to balance either other out.  This can be tricky when writing an "anonymous class" used as a listener.

```
    Frame frame = newCricleDraw();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we)
        {
            system.exit(0);
        }  // This closes the { two lines above
      }    // This closes the { just before "public"
```

At this point, you have an open `(`, just before the word `new`, so you can't close it with a `}`.  Change

```
    };//end of listener
```

to this (using a right parenthesis):

```
    ); // end of listener
```

Then, you need a semicolon after this:

```
    frame.setSize(600,600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?  It seems like there a bunch of errors that should be caught by a compiler/IDE

```
public class CircleDraw extends Frame
{
    Shape squareHead = new
    Ellipse2D.Float(200.0F, 40.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);

    Shape squareLeftArm = new
    Rectangle2D.Double(165, 230,30, 50);

    Shape circleCenter = new
            Ellipse2D.Double(165, 230, 30, 50);

    Shape squareNeck = new
    Rectangle2D.Double(165, 230, 30,50);

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        //draw head
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(squareHead);
        ga.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        ga.fill(squareHead);

        //draw arms
        ga.setPaint(Color.black);
        ga.draw(squareLeftArm);
        ga.fill(squareLeftArm);

        //draw center
        ga.setPaint(Color.CYAN);
        ga.draw(circleCenter);
        ga.fill(circleCenter);

        //draw neck

    }
}
```

And then the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Frame frame = new CircleDraw();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {   
        public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we)
        {
            System.exit(0);
      }
    });//end of listener
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now that it runs, you got some work to do on getting the shapes and location right...

[image]

Comment: I used that, then in the main window, i got an error saying " reached end of file while parsing" and it highlighted the last parenthesis.

Comment: I gave you the main method, not the whole class.  You have your class defined as `public class main {`  Besides the fact that this should be changed since classes *should* start with an upper case letter and be more descriptive.  maybe public class HumanTest.